# Can not upload large database file in phpmyadmin in linuxmint os

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 136MB database file. When I have tried to upload my database in phpmyadmin then it gives an error like `Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.`

**Note :** I have used Linux mint 17.2 os so I don't know there I have to configure file.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/411505/script-timeout-passed-if-you-want-to-finish-import-please-resubmit-same-file-a  - is it almost same question? right?

Comment: But i don't know where `config.inc.php` this file is located in lampp?

Comment: Where is your phpmyadmin folder?  in my case , "/etc/phpmyadmin" is my phpmyadmin dir.